# Catch all exceptions in a Rails 3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to catch all exceptions in a Rails 3 application. I tried to put a begin rescue around Cms::Application.initialize! (in config/environment) but it does not work:

```
begin
  Cms::Application.initialize!
rescue
  # notify me
end
```

I few words I would like to try to have a basic exception notification. I know there are plug ins and services around, but I want to do it on my own

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can catch them in your application controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from(Exception) { # Or just handle particular exceptions
  # do stuff
  }
end
```

Comment: And you've put that in application_controller.rb?

Comment: rescuing `StandardError` is usually better than `Exception`: http://awesomerails.wordpress.com/2008/10/07/rescuing-exceptions-err-i-mean-standarderror-in-ruby/